# How to determine which version of HTML is used?

Tags: html

If a page starts with the `<html>` tag and no doctype, how is it interpreted? Which version of HTML is used? Can it be interpreted by browser as HTML5 or some other version? **And how do I determine that?**

for example, see below html file.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<p> This is a paragraph </p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: From that simple code you can't determine anything. You need to check certain elements and see to which specification they belong. Browsers and validators do this automatically.

Comment: Depends on the browser, but HTML5 compliant browsers (any of the major ones now in use) parse HTML as if it was HTML5. The `DOCTYPE` is now completely optional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a page starts with the `<html>` tag and no doctype, how is it interpreted?

With [the Quirks mode parser](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html).

> Which version of HTML is used?

Browsers don't care about versions of HTML, only elements and attributes that they recognise.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article about how browsers determine rendering modes (and the modes that they have):

https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/

Most browsers use the DTD (DocType Declaration) to determine rendering mode. IE since IE8 also interpret the X-UA-Compatible meta tag to help determine.

> **Appendix: IE8’s Mode Selection**
>
> Start: Go to “X-UA-Compatible meta?”.
>
> **X-UA-Compatible meta?**
>
> ```
> IE=7: Use IE7 Standards. 
> IE=EmulateIE7: Go to “Quirky or No Doctype? (Compatibility Mode)”. 
> IE=IE8 or IE=IE7 or IE=a or IE=EmulateIE8 or absent or has script first: Go to “X-UA-Compatible HTTP Header?”. 
> IE=8 or IE=Edge or IE=99 or IE=9.9: Go to “Almost Standards Doctype?”. 
> IE=5: Use Quirks (IE 5.5).
> ```
>
> **X-UA-Compatible HTTP Header?**
>
> ```
> IE=7: Use IE7 Standards. 
> IE=EmulateIE7: Go to “Quirky or No Doctype? (Compatibility Mode)”. 
> IE=IE8 or IE=IE7 or IE=a or IE=EmulateIE8 or absent: Go to “Display All Web Sites… Pref Set?”. 
> IE=8 or IE=Edge or IE=99 or IE=9.9: Go to “Almost Standards Doctype?”. 
> IE=5: Use Quirks (IE 5.5).
> ```
>
> **Quirky or No Doctype? (Compatibility Mode)**
>
> ```
> Yes: Use Quirks (IE 5.5). 
> No: Use IE7 Standards.
> ```
>
> **Display All Web Sites… Pref Set?**
>
> ```
> Yes: Go to “Quirky or No Doctype? (Compatibility Mode)”. 
> No: Go to “Display Intranet Sites… Pref Set?”.
> ```
>
> **Display Intranet Sites… Pref Set?**
>
> ```
> Yes: Go to “Is the site in the Intranet Zone?”. 
> No: Go to “Domain on MS-Maintained List?”.
> ```
>
> **Is the Site in Intranet Zone?**
>
> ```
> Yes: Go to “Quirky or No Doctype? (Compatibility Mode)”. 
> No: Go to “Domain on MS-Maintained List?”.
> ```
>
> **Domain on MS-Maintained List?**
>
> ```
> Yes: Go to “Quirky or No Doctype? (Compatibility Mode)”. 
> No: Go to “Framed by Compatibility Mode page?”.
> ```
>
> **Framed by Compatibility Mode page?**
>
> ```
> Yes: Go to “Quirky or No Doctype? (Compatibility Mode)”. 
> No: Go to “Compatibility Mode Button Pressed?”.
> ```
>
> **Compatibility Mode Button Pressed?**
>
> ```
> Yes: Go to “Quirky or No Doctype? (Compatibility Mode)”. 
> No: Go to “Quirky or No Doctype? (IE8)”.
> ```
>
> **Quirky or No Doctype? (IE8)**
>
> ```
> Yes: Use Quirks (IE 5.5). 
> No: Go to “Almost Standards Doctype?”.
> ```
>
> **Almost Standards Doctype?**
>
> ```
> Yes: Use IE8 Almost Standards. 
> No: Use IE8 Standards.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

According to the W3C specification about `DOCTYPE` [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#doctype-syntax):

> A doctype (sometimes capitalized as “DOCTYPE”) is an special instruction which, for legacy reasons that have to do with processing modes in browsers, is a required part of any document in the HTML syntax;

and an older HTML4.01 spec about `DOCTYPE` [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#version-info):

> A valid HTML document declares what version of HTML is used in the document.

the `DOCTYPE` is a required piece of any HTML page in order to be valid HTML. Not having it will cause browsers to have a browser-specific interpretation of your page, commonly referred to as [Quirks Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). This will be different in every browser, and should never be relied on. The moral of the story is to always include a `DOCTYPE` at the very top of your page.